# How to filter CloudWatch Log Insights with ispresent() function

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm trying to perform a really simple query on the <s>not so</s> new [AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax-examples.html)

I'm following their documentation to filter my logs using `ispresent` function.

The query is the following:

```
fields @timestamp, status
| filter ispresent(status) != 0
```

But this give me an error (the super unhelpful `We are having trouble understanding the query`)

How can I filter my logs by showing only the logs with the `status` field?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After a while, I figured out how to do that, in a hackish way.

```
fields @timestamp, status, ispresent(status) as exist
| filter exist != 0
```

Not the best way (and it goes against their documentation), but works.

Comment: ```fields @timestamp, status
| filter ispresent(status)``` - this looks better

Comment: It does look better. Though, by the time of the question, it wasn't working.I can't test right now as I don't have any json formatted logs, unfortunately.

Comment: Also AWS does not have a good way to negate the `ispresent()` function from within the filter, which this makes up for. Thanks!

Answer (score 61):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me, but you can now negate `ispresent()`:

```
fields @timestamp, status
| filter !ispresent(status)
```

Comment: As a filter `ispresent()` also works with the reverse `!!ispresent()`

Answer (score 0):

The following query worked for me.

```
fields @timestamp, status
| filter isPresent(status)
```